# GMM: Under What Conditions Does Adding a Seemingly Unrelated Moment Condition Increase Efficiency?

Tags: econometrics

For simplicity, I'll offer the simplest of endogenous models. Suppose we have the following scalar model:

$y=\beta x+u$ where $E[ux]\neq 0,\;E[uz]=0\; \text{and}\;E[u^2|z]=\sigma^2$

Clearly we can use the following instrument to identify $\beta$:

$$E[(y-\beta x)z]=0$$
However, suppose we have another moment condition using another variable, $w$:
$$E[zw]=0$$
This moment condition doesn't contain any information about $\beta$, so under what conditions would we gain efficiency by using this additional moment condition?

Comment: See: Breusch, T., H. Qian, P. Schmidt, and D. Wyhowski (1999), Redundancy of moment conditions, Journal of Econometrics 91, 89-111.